# Read from file c++ program stops working

Tags: c++, file-io

i am trying to read from an text filein C++, the format of the text file is the following:

```
1 2
5 3
4 6
```

and my code looks like this:

```
std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
    int a, b;
    while (infile >> a >> b)
    {
        printf("%s, %s", a, b);
    }
```

however everytime i try to run my code the program stops working, i have tracked it until the while loop, so the code works fine until the while loop and i can't understand why. Please advice.

Comment: Does the compiler really not [give a warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/277f077835d82e89)?

Comment: no nothing, that is why i am so confused

Comment: And you have warnings turned on?

Comment: R Sahu's explained your mistake, but FWIW you can totally avoid this class of error by using e.g. `std::cout << a << ", " << b << '\n';` instead of the legacy C functions that aren't type safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifiers in `printf`. Use

```
printf("%d, %d", a, b);
```

To make the output look more like the input, use:

```
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
```

or

```
std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or even ```std::cout << a << b << "\n"``` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
        int a = 0, b;
        while (infile >> a >> b)
        {
//The correction was made in this line
// Org code -printf("%s %s", a,b); -- You wanted to print integers but 
// but informed the compiler that strings will be printed.
            printf("%d %d", a,b);
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A code only answer with no explanation of what was wrong with the code is just bad.

Comment: @Arun I hope I have corrected the mistake. Thanks for pointing it out to me